# Inserting/Updating pages via (apostrophe-headless) REST API

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm trying to Insert/Update page via apostrophe-headless REST API I'm currently using the bearerToken for all requests but I always receive the response as `{ error: 'notfound' }` i tried with all type of payloads. Even fetching a page data like `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/apostrophe-pages/cjnykgfly007lzrx4clf8jwae` is only working when an apostrophe is in draft mode. Do i missing something?

Additional Note: Deleting page from API also not working!

Comment: Are you attempting to use `apostrophe-headless` with `apostrophe-workflow`? Does the user have full permissions for the live locale?

Comment: Yes i'm attempting to use apostrophe-headless with apostrophe-workflow. Do i need to update permissions for each and every individual locale? And also i found an issue with permission is that when i apply the same permission to sub-pages it does't reflected to the sub-pages. It always passes as false when i'm debugged.

Comment: Thanks now i could generate page via REST api after providing permissions for all the locales. But i'm facing a new problem with areas and widgets are not getting saved via REST should i have to change any configurations with apostrophe-workflow module??

Comment: Since the last problem you mentioned is likely unrelated to the original question, it would probably be good to post a new question instead of adding a comment, Anwar. Good luck!